# JavaScript 4x4 grid memory game

Tags: javascript, html, css

Create a version of the 'classic' game of memory (aka concentration). There should be a 4 x 4 grid of cards laid out face-down in front of the user. When clicked, reveal the face of a card. When a second card is tapped, reveal the face of that card as well. If the two cards match, remove them from the game. If they don’t, return them to face-down and allow the user to choose two more.

**question:
how do i get the cards to flip?
how do i remove them from the game after they checked if the cards matched?
make them face down if wrong?**

```
JavaScript Code:


var card = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

//loop through cards put same listener on e

for(var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
card[i].addEventListener('click', flipCard);
}

//remove card
function flipCard(event){
var select1 = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0].className;
var select2 = "";

  
}

Html code:

<html>
<head><title> Memory</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="card myCard" >Flip</div>
<div class="card myCard" >Flip</div>
<div class="card m">Flip</div>
<div class="card c">Flip</div>
  
<div class="card m" >Flip</div>
<div class="card c" >Flip</div>
<div class="card one" >Flip</div>
<div class="card one">Flip</div>
  
<div class="card two" >Flip</div>
<div class="card two" >Flip</div>
<div class="card three">Flip</div>
<div class="card three">Flip</div>
  
<div class="card four">Flip</div>
<div class="card four" >Flip</div>
<div class="card five " >Flip</div>
<div class="card five" >Flip</div>
  
<link href= "style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style>

</style>
  
  
<!-- -->

<script src="app.js"></script>
  
</body>

</html>

Css:

.card{
float: left;
width: 100px;
height; 150px;
text-align: center;
background-color: rebeccapurple;
padding: 10px;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: did you have a question? Or did you just want us to finish your assignment?

Comment: What is this supposed to be for? what's wrong?

Comment: @RandyCasburn pretty much I just updated the post with the question sorry about that.

Comment: @MatthewProSkils I just updated the post with the question sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you were after with this but here is one way you can flip a card.

```
<html>
<head><title> Memory</title>
</head>
<body>
  <link href= "style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <style>
    .card{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height; 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

  </style>

<div class="card myCard" id = "cards">Flip</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('cards').onclick = function() {
  if(document.getElementById('cards').innerHTML === 'Flipped'){
        document.getElementById('cards').innerHTML = 'Flip';
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('cards').innerHTML = 'Flipped';
  }

       }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks you !!! Also, how do I remove them from the game after they checked if the cards matched? make them face down if wrong?

Comment: "_I'm not sure what you were after with this_" - the OP was after you to do the OP's homework assignment. The funny part is the OP probably has no intention of upvoting your homework solution nor accepting the answer (until this comment is read).

Comment: You can use removeElement(id) in this case cards. If this answer helped you please declare it finished with check mark.